# How To Freeze Screen In Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I Would Like To Manually Freeze The Screen Frame So That I Could Pause And Take Notes For Lectures. It Is Difficult To Take Screenshot Everytime.

Any Possible Solutions???

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestions But I Prefer Any Other Ways Other Than Taking Screenshots So That I Wont Get My Pictures Folder Spammed With Screen Shots.

Answer (score 1):

you can take screen shots easily here is a link on how to do it with short cuts:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b
the short cut is Windows Key + Print Screen

Answer (score 1):

its easy to do on Windows 10, just press "Windows Key + Print Screen" and done.

your screenshots will be saved automatically in Pictures->Screenshot directory.